# Tried and failed to get client id for scope com.google.api.server.spi.config.scope.SingleAuthScopeExpression

Tags: java, javascript, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-cloud-endpoints

In the Google Cloud Endpoints [migration timetable](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#email), where steps to migrate from other authentication services are described, is written that **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email** scope is **deprecated** and the migration to **email** scope should be considered (analogically from **userinfo.profile** scope to **profile** scope).

In Java class *Constants* where are defined constants like *Client ID* for my *@Api* service classes, I changed

```
public static final String EMAIL_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
```

to

```
public static final String EMAIL_SCOPE = "email";
```

Also on the client side in JavaScript [example form google](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js), I changed the *scopes* variable to

```
var scopes = 'email';
```

And in Google Developers Console logs I'm getting following exception:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.auth.AppEngineAuthUtils getCurrentUser:
getCurrentUser: AccessToken; Tried and failed to get client id for scope 'com.google.api.server.spi.config.scope.SingleAuthScopeExpression@ed8e89a9'
com.google.appengine.api.oauth.InvalidOAuthParametersException: 
    at com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(OAuthServiceImpl.java:139)
```

In my endpoint method

```
@ApiMethod(name = "authorize", httpMethod="get")
    public AppUser authorize(User user) throws NonAuthorizedException {
        ...
    }
```

in the *User user* parameter a **null** is inserted by the Engine (I was authorized of course).

This doesn't work even if I change scope to **profile**. It only works only on *localhost*, but I think, it's not the problem.

One can ask, so why could you just let it be as **userinfo.email**? I was looking for some other scopes, because occasionally for some specific google users (I don't know what is specific about them), **userinfo.email** does't work either.
Can anybody help me please? Thanks.

Comment: could it be this: issue 8848 get_current_user API doesn't fill user_id https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to update the scope. Even though the scope is deprecated, it's not going to be removed.